# Symfony 2 - one route for the controller

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

This is my first time using symfony. I have used laravel 4 before. In laravel there was a way to configure one route pattern for the entire controller. Somthing like `Route::controller('users', 'UserController');`
In there something similar in symfony?

Comment: Please read symfony2 official documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your route over the complete class. The all function routes insight are from that route.

```
/**
 * @Route("/something")
 */
class yourController extends Controller {
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Comment: One possible way using annotations. The OP should know other way using yaml, php [...]. Btw Symfony got a good documentation about routing.